# in wpf, how loop output the data in textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

The following code can only display the last number:

```
    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
       textbox.text({0},i);
```

But I want to output numbers in textbox like this;

```
    0
    1
    2
```

How can I do with it? thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `StringBuilder`, like this more or less (pseudocode):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (i=0; i<3; i++)
     sb.AppendLine(string.Format({0},i));

textbox.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Just note: if you are using `WPF` avoid direct access to the control properties and operate on `ViewModel` instead, if not, you loose notable part of the benefits brought to you with that technology.

Comment: thx for your help. I have another question: if can I have all the histroy data visible in textbox after update (that is, recieve some new data), just like the windows console does?

Comment: You have to have multiline `TextBox` control (like in this case too). But keep in mind that controls have their buffer limits, so you should laverage between what you load on UI and have in your model.

Comment: Ok. If I only have last 50 lines datum visible, how can i do ?

Comment: @TomJacky: you can try to use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Linq way

```
var result=Enumerable.Range(0,3).Select(i=>i.ToString()).Aggregate((init, next)=> init+ Environment.NewLine+next);
textBox.Text = result;
```